# netdev / asyncssh - use disable Key exchange Algo - diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

Tags: python, asyncssh

I use the netdev lib to connect to network devices. If I try to connect to old Cisco device I receive the following message.
Disconnect Error: No matching key exchange algorithm found, sent curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,curve448-sha512,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-1.3.132.0.10,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256@ssh.com,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,rsa2048-sha256 and received diffie-hellman-group1-sha1.

How can I change the behaviour with enabling the diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 algo ?

I have search in the configuration file, but don't found any solution.